# SQL Server Architecture on Production Environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to understand the best approach for SQL Server architecture on production environment.

Here is my problem:

I have database which has on average around 20,000 records being inserted every second in various tables.

We have reports also implemented for the same, now what's happening is whenever reports is searched by user, performance of other application steeps down.

We have implemented

- Table Partitioning
- Indexing
- And all other required things.

My question is: can anyone suggest an architecture that have different SQL Server databases for reports and application, and they can sync themselves online every time when new data is entered in master SQL Server?

Some what like Master and Slave Architecture. I understand Master and Slave architecture, however need to get more idea around it.

Our main tables are having around 40 millions rows (table partitioning done)

Comment: A different database is not going to save you. You are exhausting the resources the server has. Either disk or CPU. It could be a blocking issue as well. You should diagnose it and fix it rather than going nuclear with a 2nd database. Look into snapshot isolation.

Comment: I have plenty of CPU and RAM i.e. 64 core CPU and 132 GB RAM, I can take risk to get it exhausted a to a extent. Have figure out bottlenecks, deadlocks etc and got it fixed with the team. I would like to raise a solid point to the management with best architecture.

Comment: I did not get that statement. Is the problem already fixed? Indeed, you are probably not exhausting CPU but you might exhausts the disks. A separate database is almost always not the right solution because it causes more trouble than necessary.

Comment: SQL Server **2012** and up have the [AlwaysOn availability groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510230.aspx) architecture, which allows for a constantly synced replica that can be easily used for e.g. reporting etc.

Comment: @marc_s Currently we are using Sql Server 2008 R2 and we don't have any plans for upgrading it to 2012 in near future, need to plan out with 2008 R2 itself.

Comment: @usr I liked what you said about separate database is not always good, taking it a bit further, my DB is not that big i.e. around 400 GB's and around 7 tables have main data having around 40 million of rows, whenever if we do Reports and access data my other applications have a bad performance, because amount of data reports are fetching is huge(basically a read is being done)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008R2 you have database mirroring and replication available, which will keep two databases in sync.

A schema which is efficient for OLTP is unlikely to be efficient for large volume reporting.  The 'live' and 'reporting' databases should have different schema with an ETL process moving data from one to the other.  I'd would like to negotiate with the business just how synchronised the reporting database needs to be.  If the reports are processing large amounts of data they will take some time to run so a lag in data replication will not be noticed, I would suggest.  *In extremis* you could construct a solution using Service Broker to move the data and processing on the reporting server to distribute it amonst the reporting tables.

The numbers you quote (20,000 inserts per second, 40 millions rows in largest table) suggests a record doesn't reside in the DB for long.  You would have a significant load performing `DELETE`s.  Optimising these out of peak hours could be sufficient to solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks Michael, will investigate more about Service Broker. 
Data in tables are always there, that's why we did Table Pratitioning, partitioning was done for fiscal year.
I will also note point about Live and reporting database to be on different schema.